# How to csv from URL format YYYY-MM-DD.csv

Tags: python, csv, import, download

I have a problem that im trying to solve. Just to declare that i dont know how to use python and i think that my issue could be very easy for someone else.

I have a url link : https://xxxcompanyname.com/repo/YYYY-MM-DD.csv

and there are some data in there. so,  i am trying to find a solution where i can extract data for date ranges. for example from 2020-09-01 intil yesterday at once.

there is not a specific folder where you can find for example 100 csv files and you select the file you want. i can use only the url link and when i insert the date and press the enter button i see the downloaded csv file. i have found a kind of script like the below but with no results:

```
import requests
import shutil
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# enter start/end dates here, convert to datetime object
start_date = datetime.strptime('2021-08-01', '%Y-%m-%d')  # the latter arg defines the format of the given string
end_date = datetime.strptime('2021-03-12', '%Y-%m-%d')

# need to know how many days we need to loop over
day_count = (end_date - start_date).days + 1

# loop over days and download file
for i in range(day_count):
    date_str = (start_date + timedelta(i)).strftime('%Y%m%d')  # convert our datetime obj into the desired string format
    r = requests.get(f'http://https//footfall.vodafoneinnovus.com/repo/YYYY-MM-DD.csv', stream=True)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        with open(f'{date_str}.csv', 'wb') as f:
            r.raw.decode_content = True
            shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```

Do you know how to extract data and if the script i've found is close enough?

Comment: *any help please?* is not really question for StackOverflow. Check [ask].

Comment: Hello and thanks for the feedback. It is important for me as it is my first post

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
import os
import requests

today = datetime.date.today()
day_count = 15
folder_name = 'downloads' #Name for new folder

try: 
    os.mkdir(f'{folder_name}')
except:
    pass

for i in range(day_count): 
    datestr = today - datetime.timedelta(days=i)
    url = f'http://https//footfall.vodafoneinnovus.com/repo/{datestr}.csv'
    r = requests.get(url) 
    csv_file = open(f'{folder_name}/{datestr}.csv', 'wb')
    csv_file.write(r.content)
    csv_file.close()
```

This creates a new folder and inserts the wanted csv files with date as names

Comment: I updated the answer, just import requests

Comment: thank you so much for your prompt response. I run the script and i have the following error message "ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='footfall.vodafoneinnovus.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /repo/YYYY-MM-DD.csv (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000024E96897208>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))"

Comment: The connection error i have is may due to credentials i need to give?

Comment: That's very likely

Comment: how can i pass the credentials i provide to the script? I have username:xxxx , Password:xxxxx